# eclipse does not see created class in ManagedBean

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have just started working with Java Server Faces framework in the version 2.3.
I created two classes in the Java Resources/src in my project and both are stored in two separate packages. When I tried to add them to ManagedBean in Faces Configuration that is inside WEB-INF/faces-config.xml, those classes were invisible. My packages' names consist of 4 parts separated by "." (ex. first.second.third.fourth). I noticed that when the name of the single package is shortened to two parts like following first.second, then I can normally find it by hitting "Using an existing Java class" option. Why are they unavailable when the package name/ structure is more complex/deeper?

I have checked out so many settings in Eclipse finding nothing, I would really appreciate help, since using more complex package structure allows to better organize the project.

Thanks in advance!